# Wix toolset Bootstrap - Access the internal msi archive

Tags: c#, wix3.11

gI am currently migrating to WiX our old setup projects (from VS2008 to VS2019). After some time spent learning how the toolset works, I managed to create and successfully install our application via the msi package.

Since it needs the .Net Framework 4.8 in order to run, I wanted to repackage it inside a bootstrapper with all the needed checks and verifications and so on.

Sadly I have now an issue: due to backwards compatibility I need to be able to access to some properties of the included MSI package in order to create a configuration file.
What I thought was either to access directly to the msi archive (with something like `msi.Database.ExecuteScalar(blabla)`) or to somehow export the needed information.

I am not an expert on installer coding, but I'm willing to learn :D

EDIT: Since it may not be clear what is my issue I try to explain here:

I have a `MSI` package from Wix with the components and everything set up. This does install and behave correctly.

Then I have the `EXE` bootstrap package, again from Wix, with `MSI` inside, because I need to check if the target machine has the right .Net framework and such.

Then I have ANOTHER EXE, `EXE2` that needs to access to some properties of `MSI`.

With the old setup project `MSI` was left outside of `EXE` (I got two different files, no issue for our situation) and then I could access to it without any issue, but with Wix is all packed together...

Answer (score 0):

After a night of sleep I came to the simplest solution: just set **`Compressed="no"`** in the included msi et voilà, here is the separated and accessible msi package.

```
<MsiPackage 
    Id="MainPackage" 
    SourceFile="$(var.DoomsDayProject.TargetPath)" 
    DisplayInternalUI="yes" 
    Compressed="no" 
    Vital="yes" />
```